# File management app without files-app integration?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, file-management, files-app

I have built an iOS app (a file management), plus its been there in app store from a year, now when i try inserting a update now my app got rejected saying `Apps that enable users to view and select files should include items from the Files app and the user’s iCloud documents.`
Do I really want to include Files-app or is there any option to update it (bypass it) without files app.

Does apple update its policy for file management ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clause 2.5.15 says that you need to support the files app

Comment: That is my question.. whether i have to support files app thatis add fileprovider into my app ????. Since i already am using documentpicker

Comment: The rejection from Apple would seem to indicate that you do